# View a .reg file without modifying registry

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I have a registry export file from a while back. I need to retrieve some values from it (namely PATH values). However, all I can see in Registry Editor is an option to import. I need an option to *view*, which means I simply want to open the .reg file without it being imported or added to the current system registry state. How can I do that?

The file is 354 MB

Comment: Normally you just right click on a reg file and select "edit" but since it is so large use Notepad++ as suggested by Keltari.

Comment: Consider opening this file using a text editor [that supports big files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files).

Answer (score 6):

`.Reg` files are simply text files.  They can be opened in any text editor.  However, if you have a very large `.reg` file, such as an export of the entire registry or a large branch, you will need a more robust text editor, like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.8.3.html), as the file size might be to large for a simple text editor to open.

Comment: Too large for Notepad.

Comment: @Melab Really?  That must be a big reg file.

Comment: try a better text editor like Notepad++

Comment: The file is 354 MB.

Comment: @Melab I just reread your question.  Its an `export` (most likely of a whole branch), so yes it will be big.  Well, I just tested an export and got a 340MB file and was able to open it in Notepad++

Comment: @Keltari edit your answer to include using Notepad++

Comment: Are you telling me that Registry Editor contains no functionality for simply viewing `.reg` files?

Comment: @Melab The regedit.exe is used for viewing the registry of a computer - not an exported file. That is what your favorite plain-text editor is for. :)

Comment: As another option for opening very large files (as in excessively large), I frequently open Gigabyte-sized log files in Sublime Text 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Registry Workshop](http://www.torchsoft.com/en/rw_information.html) (not free, but trial available).

> Registry Workshop is an advanced registry editor. It is a perfect
>   replacement for RegEdit and RegEdt32 which shipped with Windows.

Answer (score -2):

In that case you could open the file on a linux system with the command less.
If you are on a windows system you could use the new bash for windows or cygwin to achieve that.

Comment: Sounds like an overkill. What's the benefit of installing entire Linux subsystem to view a text file rather than using a text editor, as suggested by  @Keltari and commenters?